# Unable to inflate tire

Tags: tire, innertube, stem, inflation

In the picture, the valve stem seems loose and I am able to pull it. The air pump hose does not stay attached to the valve stem when I try to inflate it. In fact, pumping air seems very easy so air is leaking and I am unable to inflate it. I can hear hissing sound of air when I pump.

[image]

Comment: What kind of pump are you using? Does it have a locking lever? If so, are you in fact locking it?

Comment: be sure that if the pump head has a flip lever on it you are using it correctly